# How can I force Visual Studio 2010 to refresh its Error List window?

Tags: html, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, validation, markup

How can I force Visual Studio 2010 to perform markup validation of my HTML and refresh its Error List window?

[image: Visual Studio 2010 Error List with markup validation warnings]

Answer (score 3):

N.B. In **VS 2017** you can often solve this by

Changing the Error List window drop down from "Build + IntelliSense" to **"Build Only"**

This and [other solutions here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/30978/vs2017-error-list-not-cleared-on-new-compile.html)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the best answer, but usually what I do is just a Shift + F6 to build my current project. You could even just slap that F6 key on its own to build your entire solution, thus refreshing the error list.